# Remove protocl and subdomain from URL

Tags: php, string

I have a string like this:

```
http://www.downlinegoldmine.com/viralmarketing
```

I need to remove `http://www.` from the string if it exists, as well as `http://` if www is not included.

In few words I just need the domain name without any protocol.

Comment: do you need the sub folder i.e /viralmarketing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) is the perfect tool for the job. You would first call it to split the url in parts, then check the hostname part to see if it starts with `www.` and strip it, then assemble the url back.

**Update: code**

```
echo normalize_url('http://www.downlinegoldmine.com/viralmarketing');

function normalize_url($url) {
    $parts = parse_url($url);

    unset($parts['scheme']);
    if (substr($parts['hostname'], 0, 4) == 'www.') {
        $parts['hostname'] = substr($parts['hostname'], 4);
    }

    if (function_exists('http_build_url')) {
        // This PECL extension makes life a lot easier
        return http_build_url($parts);
    }

    // Otherwise it's the hard way
    $result = null;
    if (!empty($parts['username'])) {
        $result .= $parts['username'];
        if (!empty($parts['password'])) {
            $result .= ':'.$parts['password'];
        }
        $result .= '@';
    }

    $result .= $parts['host'].$parts['path'];

    if (!empty($parts['query'])) {
        $result .= '?'.$parts['query'];
    }

    if (!empty($parts['fragment'])) {
        $result .= '#'.$parts['fragment'];
    }

    return $result;    
}
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/HfRJh)**.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `parse_url` (see: http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php ). It will also incorporate different protocols and paths etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$nvar = preg_replace("#http://(www\.)?#i", "", "http://www.downlinegoldmine.com/viralmarketing");
```

Test:

```
php> echo preg_replace("#http://(www\.)?#i", "", "http://www.downlinegoldmine.com/viralmarketing");
downlinegoldmine.com/viralmarketing

php> echo preg_replace("#http://(www\.)?#i", "", "http://downlinegoldmine.com/viralmarketing");
downlinegoldmine.com/viralmarketing
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way, but:

```
$url = preg_replace("#^(http://)?(www\\.)?#i", "", $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = strncmp('http://', $url, 7) ? $url : substr($url, 7);
$url = strncmp('www.', $url, 4) ? $url : substr($url, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to remove the https://, http://, and www. from a url.

```
   $url = 'http://www.downlinegoldmine.com/viralmarketing';
   echo preg_replace('/https?:\/\/|www./', '', $url);
```

above returns downlinegoldmine.com/viralmarketing

---

and you can use the following to remove the urls path as well as the https://, http://, and www..

```
   $url = 'http://www.downlinegoldmine.com/viralmarketing';
   echo implode('/', array_slice(explode('/',preg_replace('/https?:\/\/|www./', '', $url)), 0, 1));
```

above returns downlinegoldmine.com