# Remove Subdomain from URL string , keeping the rest of URL (for replacing subdomain)

Tags: php, parsing, explode

i have a location menu that has to change location, the good thing is every url exist in every city,, and every city is a subdomain

```
city1.domain.com.uk/index.php?page=category/238/12
city2.domain.com.uk/index.php?page=category/238/12
```

Im trying this.  Im trying to break the URL to remove subdomain , so i can replace it for each item in menu

I want to get `index.php?page=category/238/12`

```
<?PHP
   $protocol = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https')=== FALSE ? 'http' : 'https';
$host     = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$script   = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$params   = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

$url = $protocol . '://' . $host . $script . '?' . $params;


   // break it up using the "." 
$urlb = explode('.',$url);

// get the domain 
$dns = $urlb[count($urlb)-1];

// get the extension 
$ext = $urlb[count($urlb)+0];

//put it back together 
$fullDomain = $dns.'.'.$ext; 

  echo $fullDomain;


   ?>
```

But i Get this `php?page=category/238/12`

Also i havent think in a solution for an issue i will be facing with this..

If im looking at a product the url change to something like

```
 city2.domain.com.uk/index.php?page=item/preview/25
```

But, the products dont exist in every city , so my user will get a 404.

=(

How can i make a conditional in the process so if `page=item/preview/25`  i do replace this for

```
page=index/index
```

Comment: Don't do it that way. Use http://php.net/parse_url

Comment: I was using parsing, i just can remove http://www.  (based on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667086/remove-protocl-and-subdomain-from-url) (¿how can i change www. in that code for any subdomain not just www.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the domain as:

```
$url = "city1.domain.com.uk/index.php?page=category/238/12";

 list($subDomain, $params) = explode('?', $url);
 list($domain, $sub) = explode('/', $subDomain);

 $newUrl = $sub . "?" . $params;

 echo $newUrl;
```

Cheers!

Comment: You just miss how can i make a condition to exclude items URL... DO you have any ideas for this

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
 <?php
  $protocol = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https')=== FALSE ? 'http' : 'https';
  $host     = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  $script   = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
  $params   = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $url = $protocol . '://' . $host . $script . '?' . $params;
  $url=(parse_url($url));
  $dns = substr($url['host'],stripos($url['host'],'.')+1);
  $fullDomain =$url['scheme']."://".$dns.$url['path']."?".$url['query'].$url['fragment'];
  if (substr($url['query'],stripos($url['query'],'=')+1,stripos($url['query'],'/')-stripos($url['query'],'=')-1)=='item') {
    echo "redirect";
  } else {
    echo "don't redirect";
  }
  echo "<br>".$fullDomain;
?>
```